# How to rename Roles/Users screens in Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I need to rename the built-in "Roles" and "Users" screen in my Lightswitch 2011 application to match my screen naming convention (e.g. View Projects"). When you right-click on the name the "Rename" option is disabled.

Does this mean that this is an impossible requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to rename the Roles and Users screens in LightSwitch.  It is possible, though, to delete the standard screens in the Screen Navigation window and create your own new replacement screens.  It is a bit of a drag to do this, but I did this so that I could control the column sizes.  It only took about 15 minutes to build equivalent screens.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully this gets addressed in a later version -seems like a strange limitation...

Comment: These "limitations" are often put in place so that people that are "new to programming" can't shoot themselves in the foot. I'm not saying that I agree, just why it's done.

Comment: I'm curious how you did this?